# Vertical lines with text in Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have created a plot in Matlab. Let's assume for simplicity that I have the following plot:

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

Now I would like to add vertical lines (going from the bottom of the figure to the top) at positions x = 1, x = 3 and x = 5. Additionally, the vertical lines should have text (next to the line or on top of the line). For example, for the line at x = 1 I would like to have the text "test 1".

How can this be done? This seems to be a pretty tricky thing in Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ways to draw lines:

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y,[1 1],[-1 1],[3 3],[-1 1],[5 5],[-1 1]);
```

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y); hold on;
for ind1 = 1:2:5
  line([ind1 ind1],[min(y) max(y)],'Color',[0 0 0]);
end
```

```
x = 0:pi/100:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
A = zeros(6); A(sub2ind(size(A),1:6,[2 1 4 3 6 5])) = 1;
plot(x,y); hold on; gplot(A, [repelem(1:2:5,1,2).', reshape(repelem([1 -1],3,1).',[],1)]);
```

Etc.

Either use `hold on` and plot in several commands, or provide all inputs to your `plot` function right aways to get the desired result. Consult the documentation of the above functions for more information.

For texts refer to [`text`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
for i=1:2:5

hold on 

plot([i i],[0 1])

s=sprintf('test%1.0f', i)

t=text(i,1,s)

set(t,'Rotation',90)

end
```